# Applying MVP transformation renders nothing OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I'm trying to apply MVP Transformation to a Square in OpenGL

But, it shows nothing.

If I remove the `mvp` from the Vertex Shader, The Square Gets Rendered

**I'm using cglm as the math library, but there is no tag for it. So, I'm giving it the glm tag**

I'm uploading a `mat4` uniform to the Vertex Shader. I also tried uploading a `vec3` as uniform to the shader and it worked. So, I feel like this is more of a calculation problem than a shader problem. But I can't seem to figure it out.

### The Code

##### Creating and Uploading Matrix

```c
// Model
mat4 model = {{1.0f}};
glm_translate(model, (vec3){5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f});

// View Matrix
mat4 view = {{1.0f}};
glm_translate(view, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f});

// Projection Matrix
mat4 projection;
glm_ortho(0.0f, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0.0f, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.001f, 1000.0f, projection);

// The MVP Matrix
mat4 mvp;
glm_mat4_mulN((mat4* []){&projection, &view, &model}, 3, mvp);

// Uploading the Matrix
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvp"), 1, GL_FALSE, (float*)mvp);
```

##### Vertex Shader

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 aColor;

uniform mat4 mvp;

out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    // On removing the mvp, the square gets rendered
    // gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    fColor = aColor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenGL coordinate system is a right-handed system. In the view space, the x-axis points to the right and the y-axis points up. Since the z-axis is the cross product of the x-axis and the y-axis, it points out of the view. Projection transforms the viewing volume into a unique cube (NDC), mirroring the z-axis and converting the coordinate system from a right-handed system to a left-handed system. All geometry that is not in the viewing volume (clip space) will be clipped. Therefore, you must move the geometry along the negative z-axis between the near and far planes. e.g.:

<s>`glm_translate(view, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f});`</s>

```c
glm_translate(view, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f});
```